# GraphPlot - Having nodelabels inside of node when graph's size greather than 100

Tags: graph, julia, label, graphplot

The following MWE:

```
using Graphs
using GraphPlot, Compose, Cairo, Fontconfig

n = 100
inst_graph = SimpleGraph(n)
nodesize = 5ones(Float64, n)
nodelabelsize = 0.02*ones(Float64, n)
draw(PDF("test.pdf"), gplot(inst_graph, nodelabelsize=nodelabelsize, nodelabel=1:n, nodesize=nodesize))
```

Produces the following graph:

[image]

Which I would like to have the nodelabels strictly within the nodes. I tried many values for `nodesize` and `nodelabelsize` ranging from -2 to 5 but nothing worked.
I noticed that for smaller values of `n` it does work, but the graphs I want to display have at least 100 nodes.

Example with `n=40` which is still not perfect as the labelnode are just a little outside the nodes!
[image]

Note that what I tried to do is [from GraphPlot doc](https://juliagraphs.org/GraphPlot.jl/) with more nodes:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the size of your canvas so all fits:

```
draw(PDF("test.pdf",30cm, 20cm), gplot(inst_graph, nodelabelsize=nodelabelsize, nodelabel=1:n, nodesize=nodesize))
```

[image]